# Code found written in chalk: "JSMYCTLYCTJCBEXD19"

Tags: cipher

The code I found on the sidewalk in chalk at my local courthouse is

JSMYCTLYCTJCBEXD19

I have had trouble identifying the code type as well as the deciphered message. Any and all suggestions/help would be appreciated!

I have figured out lines 1, 2, and 4 which read
"I am up and sometimes down / in a circle, all around / [line 3] / but quake beneath their boots"

As it is shown on the picture, it appears to be a "what am i" puzzle.

Unfortunately, this is about as much as I know, and as far as context goes, I merely stumbled upon it as I was walking around my downtown area with friends.

[image]

[image]

Comment: @HTM I added pictures. I already have other three lines, but the third line is where I am stuck. Do you recognize this from somewhere and that's why you question where I found it?

Comment: Thanks, I was just making sure that this wasn't a "do this cipher from a competition for me" kind of question. As for the code itself, I don't think I've seen anything like this before - how did you decipher the other lines?

Comment: No worries! I'm sure that's super annoying. The others were a combination of alphabet substitution, pigpen cipher, and numerical substitution, so it was relatively easy, but this line has me stumped. Also, I've been trying to delete the duplicate I accidentally posted for like thirty minutes and I cannot for the life of me figure it out. So sorry.

Comment: There should be a "delete" link along the bottom of the question, above any comments.

Comment: @bobble I only see "share", "edit", or "flag" options?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Puzzling :) Could you also post the decryptions of the other parts you already worked out, please? They might provide useful context for working out this one too. With such a short ciphertext this could be a useful way to get an 'in'... Thanks!

Comment: I concur with Stiv's request, and in addition to the parts you have deciphered already, please add some context to your question. You probably didn't find this text on the ground by accident.

Comment: Thanks for posting the context :) Two thoughts. (i) The first two lines kinda rhyme - I wouldn't be surprised if the third and fourth do too; (ii) however, saying that - and given that this is a recent find on the pavement - that nineteen on the end would very much make sense if the last part of that line (non-rhyming) turns out to be 'COVID-19'...